# JS subtracting numbers when one has decimal and does not

Tags: javascript, nan, subtraction

I have two vars that I need to subtract from one another.

My code is

```
var discountedTotal = totalAmount - discountAmount;
```

`totalAmount` is static and that value is 3,916.64

`discountAmount` is entered via an input and is a round number i.e. 500

so `discountedTotal` = 3,916.64 - 500;

I am getting a result of `NAN`, what is the best way to handle this scenario? Thanks

Comment: The Problem is that the **number cannot contain comma**. `3,916.64 - 500;` ==> `416.64`. Is the first number a **string**? You can remove comma from string by using `replace`. `num.replace(/,/g, '')`

Comment: Yes I am getting it from a dd so I had to use .text()

Comment: `parseFloat(something.text().trim().replace(/,/g, ''))`

Comment: Yup you rock, that first comment did the trick. Add it as an answer please :)

Comment: You may either delete your question.

Comment: Not really the point of this site mate.

Comment: @Tushar— *trim* is redundant, *parseFloat* will trim leading and trailing whitespace anyway (see step 3 of [*the algorithm*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-parsefloat-string)). Also, in some languages, comma is used for the decimal place.

Comment: @ClintonGreen, You will find many answers for _How to remove comma from string_ hence it is not really helpful for future users and this is what Bhojendra means...

Comment: @RayonDabre I understand but I didn't know that the problem was the comma. Someone else might have the same issue and find this question useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var totalAmount = '3,916.64';
var discountAmount = 500;

totalAmount = parseFloat(totalAmount.replace(',','')); 
console.log(totalAmount); 
discountedTotal = totalAmount - discountAmount;
console.log(discountedTotal);
```

Try this. Hope it helps.